# How to dynamically parse object within a object where properties are a mix of types

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops

When trying to parse a object within a object as such:

```js
let attribute: keyof Test

for (attribute in data) {
  if (typeof data[attribute] != 'string') {
    data[attribute]['numberProperty'] = 3
  }
}
```

With the following data:

```js
var data: Test = {
  stringProperty: "someString",
  objectProperty: {
    numberProperty: 13
  }
}
```

And this interface:

```js
interface Test {
  stringProperty: string
  objectProperty: {
    numberProperty: number
  }
}
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"numberProperty"' can't be 
used to index type 'string | { numberProperty: number; }'.
  Property 'numberProperty' does not exist on type 'string | { numberProperty: number; }'.(7053)
```

Since the error complained about the string not being parsable as a object, I tried to remove it from the equation by logically emiting it and only allow objects to pass:

```
for (attribute in data) {
  if (typeof data[attribute] != 'string') { // This line is supposed to remove the string
    data[attribute]['numberProperty'] = 3
  }
}
```

However, this did not work. What can I do?

Here is a [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyyWUoA5gApQD2ADtGAJ4BcJYZI5hxNARgCsICMNXqNWuHsWQgArgFs+0MQyjM28pdGkBfQvoKEAbnCjIAJnDBw26LMgC8Uou05VaajcgBEGGgoQAMocFD4ANNL8QiKqEmz4rsRaylBx6pIAjADMegaEhAA2ENjWoXxykGwA1hBMNDBomGAFBDA05gAUZWQVkMigltZwAJQuxMCNncwMDUM2ANo9wH0QALrIAITOAOSkFDtjiTLzcEtg5ZXrCzspKp4SOxvOua6GukA) if you want to see the error in action

Comment: That's exactly it! How curious, you simply changed the `data[attribute]` to a variable and used it instead? Please do elaborate in an answer @jcalz

Comment: The way I think about it is, TypeScript isn't guaranteed that `data[attribute]` hasn't changed between when you check it and when you use it. But of course there are examples where something similar is used and TypeScript *does* narrow it, so this isn't really what TypeScript is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were expecting the check of the expression `data[attribute]` to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) its apparent type from the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | { numberProperty: number }` to `{ numberProperty: number }`.  But narrowing on property access is only supported when the key is of a single known [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type.  Since `attribute` is itself a union type (`"stringProperty" | "objectProperty"`), no such narrowing takes place.

There is a longstanding issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) requesting support for narrowing all `obj[key]` expressions even if `key` is not a single literal type... such as `string`, or a union, or a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  (The original issue was actually about all bracketed property access, but this part has since been fixed when the bracketed property is a single string literal, so `obj["prop"]` now narrows the same way `obj.prop` does.  But the issue has stayed open to track the other cases.)  It's not trivial to do this without degrading compiler performance, and so the feature remains missing.

Until and unless that changes, you need to work around it.  The recommended workaround is, where possible, to copy the expression you want to narrow to its own variable, since variables can be narrowed as expected.  In your example that would look like:

```
let attribute: keyof Test
for (attribute in data) {
  const val = data[attribute];
  if (typeof val !== 'string') {
    val['numberProperty'] = 3 // okay
  }
}
```

which compiles with no error because `val` is indeed narrowed by the check from `string | { numberProperty: number }` to `{ numberProperty: number }`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyyWUoA5gApQD2ADtGAJ4BcJYZI5hxNARgCsICMNXqNWuHsWQgArgFs+0MQyjM28pdGkBfQvoKEAbnCjIAJnDBw26LMgC8Uou05VaajcgBEGGgoQAMocFD4ANNL8QiKqEmz4rsRaylBx6pIAjADMegaEhAA2ENjWoXxykGwA1hBMNDBomGCEMDTmABRlZBWQyKCW1nAAlC7ECDQgDqaFToM2ANrdwL0QALoA3NLAjR3MDA3IM8gAhI7OAOSkFBejiTJHcIULFykqnhIXa3PZyAD0f2QNGqcCYeQIuiAA)